# Disable the up/down keys to control the volume

Tags: mediaelement.js

In a wordpress site with the mediaelement.js only for playing audio files along the pages, i need to override the up/down from the keyboard as it changes the volume up/down when scrolling the page after clicking the play button, does one know or have an hint how to override this keyboard.

Thank's in advance for helping.

Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Set the `enableKeyboard` property of your control to false;

```
$('myMediaElement').mediaelementplayer({
    //other properties...
    enableKeyboard: false
});
```

Comment: Thank's for the quick answer, i found that on media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.js but still with false i keep moving the volume up/down with the keyboard, maybe it's not this one the file to change.

Comment: Check the installation instructions (step 3 is where you can change the options found in step 4) http://www.mediaelementjs.com/#installation